# MS-Access criteria: get 2 digits for months

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, criteria

This is the query that I have, which is months in two digits. 
[image]

My goal is finding the right criteria to retrieve one month ago from today or this month, in two digits. 
 [image]
Currently `Month(now())` gives 10, but I hope to get 09, not 9.
I tried DateSerial, getDate(), pretty anything I could think of or online. But none of them worked. Any advice on this would be highly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Now()), "MM")
```

The `DateAdd` part substracts the current date by one month, the `Format` part outputs the month in the `MM` format (with leading zero)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. But I'm getting 'the expression you entered contains invalid syntax" It happened to me before when I tried' Format' function. Could you please give me any advise on this? Thanks!

Comment: If you enter it as an expression in the query builder, you need to replace all comma's `,` with semicolons `;`

Comment: Thank you SO much! It works like a charm. Hope you have a great day! Thank you again!